# Android Development: Webview progress Bar

Tags: android

Take a look at: http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/msg/61802d28a8335809

ive done that a got it to work but the progress does not change when clicking on a link in the webbrowser.

So the progressbar is showed when the app starts and load the home URL but when i click a link or search in google the bar is not showed. why?

Thank-you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

ProgressDialog MyDialog;

```
      public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,String description,String failingUrl) {

Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description,
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
@Override 
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {   
activity.setProgress(progress * 1000); 
view.loadUrl(url); 
return true; 
 }

    });
```